# How to get a dropdown list to display above a silverlight control?

Tags: silverlight

I have a textbox that when you put focus into it, it drops down some values.  Next to the textbox is a silverlight control, a canvas.  The problem is that part of the dropdown displays behind the silverlight control.  Is there a property I can set on one of the elements so it is diplayed on top of the silveright control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem with hover hints and dropdown lists as well. Try setting the `windowless` property of the silverlight control to `true`.

Eg:

```
<object id="yourSilverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="500">
    <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/yourSilverlightControl.xap"/>
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <param name="windowless" value="true" />
</object>
```